# UINavigationBar drawRect Alternative (aka, Need CoreGraphics calls in a category)

Tags: objective-c, uikit, core-graphics, drawrect

I recently discovered that in > iOS5 UINavigationBar does not get its drawRect called. I want to figure out how to draw with Core Graphics in a category.

The end goal I am trying to achieve is eliminating images from my app and have everything drawn at runtime. I am also trying to make this library automatic, so that users don't have to think about using my custom classes.

Is there a way to replace a class with one of your own at runtime? like: `replaceClass([UINavigationBar class], [MyCustomBar class]);`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, Instead of messing with draw rect, I just made some methods that draw to a UIImage then set the image as the background view for the elements i am customizing. It makes my custom UI magic again.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to replace a class with one of your own at runtime?

In Objective-C this is know as [class posing](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/ClassPosing).

Class posing is based on the use of `NSObject`'s `poseClass` method, which is now deprecated (on 64 bit platforms, including the iPhone).

Alternative approaches have been investigated; you can read about one [here](http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2007/11/25/working-without-a-nib-part-6-working-without-a-xib/), but they do not seem quite to fit the bill.

Comment: The problem with this method, is that even if I swap drawRect in UINavigationBar with my own method, drawRect is not called in iOS5 or newer.